# htaccess rewrite direct photo link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the direct photolink: http://upload.domain.com/image-upload/date/original-generated_name.jpg
It is a direct link to a photo info a uploadscript.
This direct link bust be redirected to: http://upload.domain.com/view/genarated_name.jpg into the htacces I have now (without any redirect options).

```
# BEGIN Scripteen FREE Image Hosting Script
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# general catch-all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
# END
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://upload.domain.com/view/genarated_name.jpg` in your browser?

Comment: @anubhava,

Then I go to this URL i get the page with the picture on the screen.
(page with ads)
This is the correct destination.

When I go to `http://upload.domain.com/image-upload/date/original-generated_name.jpg` the result must be `http://upload.domain.com/view/genarated_name.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^image\.uploads/[^/]+/original-(.+)$ /view-image/$1 [NC,L,R=302]

# general catch-all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, the date is a variable. See for the example url: http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/image.uploads/22-06-2014/original-92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg needs to rediretc to url: http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/view-image/92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg (18+ ADULT ALERT!!!)

Comment: I add it, page will redirect to the correct URL, only message No Image found with this name :-( Thanks for your advice Anubhava

Comment: That is why I asked earlier `What happens when you enter http://upload.domain.com/view/genarated_name.jpg in your browser?` and you wrote you get the page with picture. How did it become `No Image found` now?

Comment: Anubhava, see example I gave, this are real working links.
I remove the line n the htaccess so you can see whats happens,

Comment: Of course I saw that. How can I comment and answer without looking at your question and examples.

Comment: OK, and now? Is there a solution?

Comment: You need to first respond to question I asked in my previous comment. How `http://upload.domain.com/view/genarated_name.jpg` worked for you earlier but giving 404 now?

Comment: When I go to the example url `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/view-image/92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg` I get the page with the picture in it. (Page view-image.php)

Comment: Code to load the image: `<?php

if(isset($error)) {
 echo do_error($error);
}else{
 
 if(isset($image_details)) {
  
 $image_main = $image_details->image_name;
 $image_size = getimagesize(image_path($image_details, $type = 'original', $image_details->image_srv));
 
 $image_width = ($image_size[0] > 640) ? 640 : 'original';
 $hasThumbanil =  ($image_size[0] > 124) ? TRUE : FALSE; 
 $user = ($image_details->username == null) ? 'Guest' : '<a href="'.SITE_URL.'/user-gallery/' . $image_details->username . '">' . $image_details->username . '</a>';  
 ?>`

Comment: And what URL are you getting in your browser after redirect from above suggested rule of mine? Isn't it this URL: `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/view-image/92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg` ?

Comment: when I go to URL (1) `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/image.uploads/22-06-2014/original-92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg`with the redirect code `RewriteRule ^image.uploads/[^/]+/(.+)$ /view-image/$1 [NC,L,R=302]` I get the URL (2): `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/view-image/original-92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg` and that give the error: No Image found with this name. The URL what works for this picture (3) is `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/view-image/92dbbfa4e0d3e79de7293de28ef9ae87.jpg` Conclusion: url 1 needs to go url 3

Comment: Oh got it, `original-` needs to be removed from URL. See my updated rule now.

Comment: It still have the original- into the url with `RewriteRule ^image.uploads/[^/]+/(.+)$ /view-image/$1 [NC,L,R=302]

Comment: Yes try my updated rule, I have taken care of it now.

Comment: Isn't it what you expected as final URL?

Comment: Hi Anubhave, the url `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/image.uploads/23-06-2014/original-6fd3db153a781f190e585475c88b385e.jpg` redirect to: `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/image.uploads/23-06-2014/original-6fd3db153a781f190e585475c88b385e.jpg` but no picture

Comment: I think you had bad copy/paste since both URLs are same in your comment.

Comment: `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/image.uploads/23-06-2014/original-6fd3db153a781f1‌​90e585475c88b385e.jpg` will redirect to `http://upload.anonymousxxl.nl/view-image/6fd3db153a781f1‌​90e585475c88b385e.jpg`

Comment: Anubhava, do you got my mail?

Comment: Yes I responded to that but email got bounced. I couldn't access your ftp host from my work due to firewall issue. I will try from home tonight.

Comment: Do you want `/image-upload/` OR `/image.upload/` to be redirected?